# Pc wont boot after Linux Booting

Tags: boot, bios, power

I installed Tails from one USB stick to another on my PC (with Windows). Its is a tablet with touch screen, so Gnome making a problems and randomly makes a screen black.

So I started Tails (installed on a second USB) in Troubleshooting mode to change the Gnome, it booted the BIOS, I choose boot from USB stick, it showed a Linux start screen and became black. I tried buttons, it didn't work. So I long-pressed power button - nothing happened.

And from that time I'm not able to start a PC with power-button - its just black, without reaction, even if I long press it... But the charge-led lightning if I plug charger. Where could be the problem please?

Comment: Have you changed the boot order to the original settings? If not, why?

Comment: I didn't change it. Just clicked Boot from USB storages etc... I want to let windows to be default

Comment: So please open UEFI settings ("BIOS") and check the boot order. Installing Tails is likely to have changed it. You must familiarize yourself with your hardware's firmware if you're going to install OSes.

Comment: BTW, the whole point of Tails is to run live, not be installed. There are proper desktop Linux distros where all you have to do is install TOR browser for the same features you get from an installed Tails.